# изменение размера блока

Tags: javascript

есть блок

```
    <div class="block_menu" id="fixed">           
        <table ">
        <tr><td >Data</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Favourites</td></tr>            
        <tr><td >Exit</td></tr>                
        </table>       
    </div>
```

как можно подстроить этот блок на всю высоту экрана. Пробовал так, но я так понимаю дело не в изменении стиля

```
window.addEventListener('onload',function(){
    changeWindow = document.body.clientHeight;
    document.getElementById('fixed').style.height = changeWindow;
},false);
```

Comment: Блок на всю высоту экрана можно сделать с помощью css. Зачем это делать с помощью js?

Comment: на css поменять получилось, но там проблема в том, что этот самый блок "прилипает" и по скроллу вниз , если добавлять контент , остается фиксированным

Comment: А так в самом скрипте ошибка, `style.height` должно быть в "px"

Comment: подождите, но что если сделать абсолютный блок во всю ширину экрана, он не прилипнет как `position:fixed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с jQuery:

```
function setHeight() {
    $('.block_menu').css({
        height: $(window).height() + 'px'
    });
}
setHeight(); // при загрузке окна
$(window).resize( setHeight ); // при изменении размеров окна
```

Можно через CSS (не очень универсальный вариант):

```
height: 100vh;
```

В вашем случае через JS надо указать единицы измерения высоты, т.к. в переменной у вас просто число:

```
document.getElementById('fixed').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: спасибо за вариант, но хотелось бы разобраться на js

Comment: дополнил ответ для вашего варианта через js

Comment: я думал, что тут как раз px нужно указывать в стиле, но Ваш вариант увы не работает

Comment: тогда попробуйте так: window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('fixed').style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
}; - вот пример http://codepen.io/lexxl/pen/dGpVyN

Comment: ну или рабочий вариант конкретно вашего кода: window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    changeWindow = window.innerHeight;
    document.getElementById('fixed').style.height = changeWindow + 'px';
},false);